# Can I change the orientation of the in-app purchase login view?

Tags: iphone, orientation, in-app-purchase, loginview

I was wondering if it is possible to change the orientation of the in-app purchase login view.

In my app, all of the messages coming from the iTunes store show up oriented according to my app settings.  My app is in landscape mode, and the messages show up likewise.

However, when the user needs to login to iTunes to initiate the purchase, the login comes up in portrait mode.

Is it possible to change this?  Or is this a limitation of that particular view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen anything related to iTunes in landscape. It think this is the limitation of the view.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have figured too.  And congratulations... as the first answer in 9 months, yours is accepted.